# Set df's column value based on several conditions from another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to set the value to the dataframe based on values from another dataframe

Example:

df1

```
A   |  B  |  C  |               
100   20.1        
100   21.3
100   22.0
100   23.6
100   24.0
100   25.8
```

df2

```
A   |  B  |  D

100   20     AC1
100   22     AC2 
100   23     AC3
100   25     AC4
100   29     AC5
200   20     AC1
200   34     AC2
200   37     AC3
```

I want df1['C'] to have something like

```
AC1
AC1
AC2
AC3
AC3
AC4
```

I.e `df1['C'] = df2['D'].where((df2['A'] == df1['A']) & (df2['B'] < df1['B']))`

Comment: So they also need to match on  column `A`? Is looking at `B` not enough?

Comment: yes, the have to match on column A

Answer (score 3):

You could `pd.merge` and `ffill` to fill missing values:

```
df1['C'] = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on = ['A', 'B']).fillna(method='ffill')['D']
```

**Output**

```
+---+-----+----+-----+
|   |  A  | B  |  C  |
+---+-----+----+-----+
| 0 | 100 | 20 | AC1 |
| 1 | 100 | 21 | AC1 |
| 2 | 100 | 22 | AC2 |
| 3 | 100 | 23 | AC3 |
| 4 | 100 | 24 | AC3 |
| 5 | 100 | 25 | AC4 |
+---+-----+----+-----+
```

**EDIT : explanation**

First we merge `df1` and `df2` on `A` and `B` columns:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on = ['A', 'B'])
#output
+---+-----+----+-----+
|   |  A  | B  |  C  |
+---+-----+----+-----+
| 0 | 100 | 20 | AC1 |
| 1 | 100 | 21 | AC1 |
| 2 | 100 | 22 | AC2 |
| 3 | 100 | 23 | AC3 |
| 4 | 100 | 24 | AC3 |
| 5 | 100 | 25 | AC4 |
+---+-----+----+-----+
```

To fill missing values, we take leverage of the `ffill` method ([see docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)):

> method : {‘backfill’, ‘bfill’, ‘pad’, ‘ffill’, None}, default None
>   Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series pad / ffill: propagate last valid observation forward to next valid backfill / bfill: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on = ['A', 'B']).fillna(method='ffill')
#output : missing values are filled as expected 
+---+-----+----+------+-----+
|   |  A  | B  |  C   |  D  |
+---+-----+----+------+-----+
| 0 | 100 | 20 | None | AC1 |
| 1 | 100 | 21 | None | AC1 |
| 2 | 100 | 22 | None | AC2 |
| 3 | 100 | 23 | None | AC3 |
| 4 | 100 | 24 | None | AC3 |
| 5 | 100 | 25 | None | AC4 |
+---+-----+----+------+-----+
```

`df1['C']` is just the `D` column of the merged and filled dataframe, which is what we wanted

```
df1['C'] = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on = ['A', 'B']).fillna(method='ffill')['D']
```

Comment: This is a neat solution @sebastien :) Was trying with merge_asof, which apparently does not handle merging on multiple columns

Comment: @sebastien my example was a little bit incorrect. Please, check it again. I'm sure there has to be condition smth like (df1.B > df2.B) because values don't have to be absolutely the same. That's why merge func will not work for my case((

Comment: thank you, but it still not works for my case (df1.B contain (integer) boundaries and df2.A contain (non-integer) values (that always are non-integers (for example 20.1, 22.6 e.t.c). So merge func will not working in this case